# X11 undock a window from system tray

Tags: c, x11

I have docked a window using SYSTEM_TRAY_REQUEST_DOCK, _NET_SYSTEM_TRAY_OPCODE

however I can't work out how to undock it!

I've tried many things in many different orders
(seemingly I should only need to clear _XEMBED_INFO property for it to end? - but that doesn't work)

```
        Atom xembedAtom = XInternAtom(disp, "_XEMBED_INFO", True);
        //long data[] = {XEMBED_VERSION, XEMBED_MAPPED};
        long data[] = {0, 0};
        XChangeProperty(disp, parentWin, xembedAtom, xembedAtom, 32, PropModeReplace,(unsigned char*) data, 2);
        XUnmapWindow(disp,parentWin);
        XSync(disp, False);

        XReparentWindow(disp, parentWin, root, 100, 100 );          
        XSync(disp, False);

        XMapWindow(disp,parentWin);
        XRaiseWindow(disp,parentWin);
        XSync(disp, False);
        XMapWindow(disp,childWin);
        XRaiseWindow(disp,childWin);
        docked=False;
```

Comment: I think it is not supposed to be undocked. You should create a separate window specifically for docking it. When its time in the dock is over, delete it altogether, or perhaps unmap it.

Comment: icky libx11 programming is horrible, no wonder people want Weston!

Comment: What does Weston bring to the table in this specific case? Does it have `weston_tray` and `weston_untray` or something?